# Using bitcoind json-rpc with multiple wallets

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, json-rpc

Since some time bitcoind can have more wallets, there are commands: https://bitcoincore.org/en/doc/22.0.0/rpc/wallet/loadwallet/ and https://bitcoincore.org/en/doc/22.0.0/rpc/wallet/listwallets/

Does it mean that it is possible to run multiple wallets in parallel with single blockchain?

If so how do I send coins from particular wallet then? Eventually how do I list transactions from particular wallet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does it mean that it is possible to run multiple wallets in parallel with single blockchain?

Yes.

> If so how do I send coins from particular wallet then? Eventually how do I list transactions from particular wallet?

Depending on the context:

- With `bitcoin-cli`, you have to add the `-rpcwallet=WALLETNAME` command line argument if there is more than 1 wallet loaded.
- With `bitcoin-qt` (the GUI), there is a dropdown UI element for selecting the wallet.
- With the JSON-RPC protocol exposed by `bitcoind` (and used by `bitcoin-cli`), there is a different HTTP endpoint for every wallet (`http://localhost:8332/wallet/WALLETNAME` instead of just `http://localhost:8332`).

When only one wallet is loaded, none of this is needed, and every request will be directed to the one loaded wallet.

Comment: this is very hard to find in official docs